# ¿Qué significa la consulta? ¿En concreto que significa la parte en negrita? ¿Qué filtrados está realizando?

Tags: sql

```
 SELECT "res_partner".id 
 FROM "**res_partner" 
 WHERE (("res_partner"."active" = true)  
 AND  ("res_partner"."supplier_rank" > 0)) 
 AND (((("res_partner"."partner_share" IS NULL 
 or "res_partner"."partner_share" = false** )  
 OR  ("res_partner"."company_id" in (1)))  
 OR  "res_partner"."company_id" IS NULL )  
 AND  ((("res_partner"."type" != 'private') 
 OR "res_partner"."type" IS NULL)  
 OR  "res_partner"."type" IS NULL )) 
 ORDER BY "res_partner"."display_name"
```

Comment: Esto es un tipo de sql, pero con algo de modificaciones, que dbms estas usando

Comment: Es un registro de Odoo.